# Node.js Net Sockets: Can't connect to multiple IP's

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket

i want to readout data from 2 diffrent IP adresses. But i always get "EALREADY" Error.
Which means that the Socket is "already in use", although i'm destroying the socket after i received the data.

If i remove the for loop and only readout 1 adress, it works just fine...

If i'm adding timeouts they won't fire... and i don't know why either.

```
var socket = new net.Socket(); 
var test = [];
test[0] =  '10.5.0.5';
test[1] =  '10.5.0.11';

for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++) {

   socket.connect('2711', test[i], function() {
      socket.write('d\n');
      console.log("1");
      console.log(test[i]);

   socket.on('data', function(data) {
      data = data.toString();
      console.log(data);
      socket.destroy();
      console.log("2");
   });
 });
}
```

Help highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "For loop" is synchronous but ".connect" and ".on('data'" are asynchronous, therefore the for loop finished before the first connection happens. The second connection attempt happens when first one is still in progress, that is why you get connection error.

You should try a recursive function, advancing step by step. For example I create a function that receives an array, and iterate the first element of array, connect, and on data close it and call again the function if array still has more items.

```
var socket = new net.Socket(); 
var test = [];
test[0] =  '10.5.0.5';
test[1] =  '10.5.0.11';


function testIP(test){

   socket.connect('2711', test.shift(), function() {
      socket.write('d\n');
      console.log("1");

   socket.on('data', function(data) {
      data = data.toString();
      console.log(data);
      socket.destroy();
      console.log("2");
      if( test.length > 0 ){
        testIP(test);
      }
   });
}
testIP(test);
```

Bonus: There are [libraries in Node.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) to work with asynchronous tasks

Comment: Works! Thank you very much. I never even heard of .shift(), i should have a look. Also i'm having a hard time handling all the async / sync stuff. it's quite hard as a beginner like me.